# Reading and Updating Data Using SqlDataAdapter Question

Tags: data-access-layer, sqldataadapter

I'm looking for some examples on how to best use SqlDataAdapter to access and update data in my application.
Right now I have something like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter;
DataSet myData = MyDataAccessClass.GetData("Select * from Students", ref adapter);
// change some data here and save changes
adapter.Update();
```

All of this occurs in code behind, and I dont really like it at all.
So, I'm trying to find a way to do something like this:

```
DataSet myData = MyDataAccessClass.GetStudents();
// change some data and save changes
MyDataAccessClass.SaveStudents(myData);
```

Where `SaveStudents` method still uses SqlDataAdapter to update db.

Any ideas on how to make this work or some pointers to best practices of doing 
something like this are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a fairly basic Data Access Layer implementation, to me.  Generally, I do it something like this:

```
public class MyDataAccessClass
{
    private string ConnString;

    public MyDataAccessClass()
    { //Get connection string from configuration file }

    public MyDataAccessClass(string connString)
    { ConnString = connString; }

    public DataSet GetAllStudents()
    {
       //your SQL Adapter code here...
    }
}
```

One note that I'd make is that with so many ORM solutions (including just Entity Framework and Linq2Sql) available, you may want to consider using collections of objects instead of data-sets for your Data Representations.  Then you can have a method like:

```
public void CreateUpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    //update database
}
```

That's fairly subjective, I'll admit, but I find it preferable to using straight DataSets.

Comment: Your example is similar to what I have, with exception that GetAllStudents method returns a ref to sqldataadapter used to get data, and then its being used in my UI code behind to make updates. I'm trying to change it so I don't have sqldataadapters in my codebehind, because i dont think its the right place for them. And at the same time I still have to use sqldataadapter to make updates in my DAL.

Comment: Also, I'm all for Entity Framework and objects instead of datasets, but unfortunately on this specific project I don't have an option of what to use for my DAL.

Comment: At some point you're still going to have to have a class that queries the database.  Whether that's directly in your code behind, or in some other referenced assembly won't change the fact that SOME piece of code is going to do it.  I normally have a separate project called SolutionName.DAL (or .DATA) which my Business Layer then references.  Usually, I can set it up so that presentation layer isn't even aware of the Database.

Comment: Right, and my codebhind does have a reference to another class that does all of the database interaction with exception of updates that are done through sqldataadapter in codebehind. Maybe I'm trying to do too much, but it just seems to me that UI codebehind is not the right place for sqldataadapter, and it should go into my database access class instead.

Comment: Did you found any better answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get update data using the sql-data-adapter then you could use these

Using System.Data.SqlClient;

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=abcd-pc;Initial Catalog=user_info;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {

            da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update logindemo set password=@pswd where username=@uname",con);
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@pswd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpass.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.Text;
            con.Open();
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "Data Updated";
            con.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
            Label1.Text = "Unable To Connect";
        }
```

I hope you understand how to update the data easily. It just like the example. You can use these type of example in Inserting into the Data, and Deleting the Data with using specific the command and sql query as it required.